# Appending filename and path in Batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm having a hard time learning how to use command lines and the using batch files.

What I want to do is write a custom path and then add the filename so that the output could be saved there.

This is what I have

```
@echo none
REM Optimizing JPEG with jpegtran
forfiles /p %1 /s /m "*.jpg" /c "cmd /c echo processing @path && c:\users\myname\desktop\jpegtran.exe -optimize -progressive -copy none -outfile "c:\users\desktop\output\"@filename @path"
pause
```

pretty much I would just like the following to happen

```
-outfile "c:\users\desktop\output\"@file
-outfile "c:\users\desktop\output\filename.jpg"
```

Not sure how I would go about doing this

Comment: use `@file`, not `@filename`

Comment: @MAKZ thanks, made the change. However that doesn't really fix the problem.

Comment: is replacing `forfiles`  by simple `for` an option? if so you can use `for /f %x in ('dir /b *.jpg') do echo processing %~fx && c:\users\myname\desktop\jpegtran.exe -optimize -progressive -copy none -outfile c:\users\desktop\output\%x
`

Comment: @MAKZ it tells me "&& was unexpected at this time."

Comment: If this is for Vista or later, maybe PowerShell would be a better solution.

Comment: `for /f %x in ('dir /b *.jpg') do echo processing %~fx && "C:\Users\MAKZ\Documents\Lightshot\jpegtran.exe" -optimize -progressive -copy none %x  C:\Users\MAKZ\Desktop\output\%x` ... i downloaded jpeg tran and ran that command and it worked . note that output folder must exist. also  i did not use -outfile